# Product filter using attributes

Tags: attributes, category, filter

How to filter products shown on the category pages based on the products attributes???
I should be able to filter the products based on the attributes such as manufacturer price color etc shown on the layered navigation menu.

Answer (score 2):

In the Magento Backend, under *Catalog > Manage Attributes*, select the attribute in question and set "Used for Sorting in Product Listing" to "Yes".